# Lost tabs bar in jgrasp

Tags: settings, jgrasp

I lost the horizontal bar that lets you switch tabs in jgrasp.  I have searched for a solution but can't even word the question in the proper way. I tried to reinstall jgrasp but that didn't work.

I uploaded a picture to show exactly what I mean.  There use to be a menu in the bar I circled.  Does anyone know how I can get it back so I can use more then one tab?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The bar (it's not really tabs, more like the Windows taskbar but it acts like tabs if you have the windows default to maximized) is in auto-hide mode. If you hover the mouse just below the horizontal scrollbar in the circled area, it will pop up. Then you can right click on it and turn off auto-hide.